# Unable to set maven in groovy script

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using groovy script in jenkins pipeline job and I need maven to execute my stage.

I do not have control of .profile as it is running on slave. I need to set the Maven in my groovy script so that I can run `man clean compile`.

maven is located at /opt/runtime/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn.

I am very new to groovy and want to know how to use this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you want to learn how to use something, the first place to look is at the associated documentation. Your question has no defined statement ("*[I] want to know how to use this*"), making it literally impossible for us to answer it. Please see the guidelines regarding [what is on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// Maven location
def mvnHome = tool name: 'maven 3_3_9', type: 'hudson.tasks.Maven$MavenInstallation'
env.MAVEN_HOME = mvnHome

// Begin Compile
stage concurrency: 1, name: 'compile'
sh '''${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/mvn clean compile'''
```

Please note that the tool name comes from the Maven configuration you have defined in the Global Tool Configuration page.